# how to pass label in 3 tier architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

how to pass the label if the user is valid or not ,i am using 3 tier architecture with app setting .so can you guide me how to pass the label whether the user is valid or not

```
     public static int login(string UserName, string Password)
            {

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();
                con.Open();
                int userid = 0;
                string selectstr = "select UserName,Password from Registration  where UserName =' " + UserName + " ' And  Password = ' " + Password + " ' ";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = selectstr;
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                userid = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd = null; 
                con.Close();

                return userid;

           if(......... ?)
{
labet.Text = " valid";
} else
{
label.Text = " not valid";
```

Comment: You are using `ADO.NET` architecture but you are defeating its purpose. Please do parameterized the query. `:)`

Comment: bro i want to just validate  the user and show the message valid or in valid

Comment: **Please** do not concatenate SQL statements like this. Eventually someone will enter `' OR 1=1;--` in the UserName field... Beware of SQL Injection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
userid = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

will give you single object.

you will have to use `cmd.ExcuteReader()` instead.

Or you can count the number of user using your query

```
string selectstr = "select 
                         count(UserName)                             
                     from 
                         Registration  
                      where 
                         UserName ='" + UserName + "' 
                         And  Password = '" + Password + "'";
```

and see the count.

Comment: You'll want to not do this, to avoid SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @Poldie thanks for your concern. But it won't be affected if you use `microsoft.security.application.encoder` before sending it to the function.

Answer (score -1):

Your code can be optimized a lot. First of all i must tell, you better use parameters, try-catch and ExecuteScalar. ExecuteScalar will return you a one-cell integer. With that you can validate users authentication.

EDIT:

```
    public static void login(string UserName, string password)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            string selectstr = "select count(id) from Registration  where UserName=@username And  Password=@password";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectstr, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

            int result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();

            if (result == 1)
            {
                label.Text = "valid";
                //valid
            }
            else
            {
                //not
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want him to sort out the hosting for your site too?

Comment: hey i cant get label.text it is invalid

Comment: -1 `ExecuteScalar will return you a one-cell integer` are you sure?

Comment: i used to use it for retrieving integer, but after your comment i saw it dont have to be int. thanks.